# Chars and foreign letters c++ throws Debug Assertion Failed

Tags: c++, visual-studio, encoding, utf-8

When I'm trying to compile and run this code in Visual Studio, it throws a Debug Assertion Failed error.

```
        char c = 'æ';
```

I believe it has to do with the encoding and the compiler, but my file is saved in the uft-8 format. I also tried to add /utf-8 to Additional Options on the properties page as specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8?view=vs-2019), but it didn't solve the problem. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Is the declaration what throws the error? Didn't you use functions like `isalpha()`?

Comment: Just because you are using utf8 doesn't mean a utf8 character, or glyph, can fit in a char.

Comment: Read [Character types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/fundamental-types-cpp?view=vs-2019#character-types).

Comment: `æ` is two bytes `\xc3\xa6`.  It won't fit in one `char`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `string`. `char` is not suitable for output `æ` .

```
string c="æ";
for (int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++)
{
    cout << c[i];
}
```

[image]